# Strange CSS Border Issue

Tags: html, css, border

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:white;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
}

#wrapper{
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:550px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>advanced website one</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="advanced1.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
   <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo image"/>
    <ul id="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
<content>    
 <h2>About Blue Micro</h2>
 <p>Blue Micro is meant for a site that doesn't necessarily need a huge amount of content. I've found that trying to put a small amount of text onto a large template ends up in a site that looks slightly off. So this template is for those that need a quick and simple site</p>
 <h2>Titles are H1 Tags</h2>
 <p>Try to include your keywords in the titles since they are what seach engines pick up, it's also a good idea to try to include those same keywords in the title as well (only one of two of your best ones).</p>
 <h2>Background Image</h2>
 <p>I debated using a fancy background for this template, but ultimately just decided to keep it blank. I did however create all the images with Alpha transparency, which means that regardless of what background you choose, it will always look good. So keep it white, or experiment with it if you please.</p>
 <h2>XHTML 1.1</h2>
 <p>This template validates as XHTML 1.1 - this is to ensure it'll work for many years to come, and it makes it really easy for you to modify.
 
 Try to include your keywords in the titles since they are what seach engines pick up, it's also a good idea to try to include those same keywords in the title as well (only one of two of your best ones).</p>
</content>
<footer>
<a href="#">free xhtml template by web page designer</a>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do this "see border" border in css, its not that hard but i'm newbie at web development. This border is linear gradient and has radius and i think internal radius 
here is the logo image [logo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MirOA.png)

[border](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/bluemicro/)

Comment: So whats the "issue" you're mentioning in the title? Any attempts?

Answer (score 0):

```
.border {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(gradient_rectangle_back.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #4586F1;
    width: 547px;
    margin-left: 14px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 }
```

You also need to download this graphic

http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bryantsmith/bluemicro/gradient_rectangle_back.png

Comment: There is, it's a thin line all the way on the left, it's hard to see :)

Comment: To download an image you right click on it with your mouse and click "Save As" make sure to save it with the same name. It's easier to see the image, if you're browser is not maximized.

Comment: no no i downloaded the image but the code for the border didn't work!